# How to count employees that have been promoted?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to figure out how to come up with a calculation or query to count the number of employees by grade promoted on each pay period.

*count the number of records who's value in grade have increased by pay period.

Sample solution:
Soln:

1. Year    Payroll Period  Count
2. 2018    *16*                2
3. 2019    *6*             1
4. 2019    *10*              1

I've tried pivot and queries in access but I think this needs to have an inner join to identify specific employees who got promoted. thanks for the assistance.

code in excel that seems to work but needs to be transferred in access due to the number of records. I think inner join would make this work. `=AND(B2<>B3,C2=C3,D3>D2)`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on **EXCEL**, you can derive your solution, assuming that your records are in sequence for columns **Year**, **Payroll**, **Employee** & **Grade**.

Add another column to determine if there is a grade increase for that particular **Payroll Period**.

[image: add column]
For excel cell reference sake, "**Year**" is in cell **A1**

Set formula of 1st cell of this column to `false`
[image: set 1st cell of new column to false]

For the next cell in this new column, set it as such:
[image: formula for checking grade increase]
The above checks if there is a grade increase for that particular **Payroll Period**.
The explanation of the formula in sequence is as such, `1. Check if year same (A3=A2)`, `2. Check if Payroll Period is different(B3<>B2)`, `3. Check if Employee is the same (C3=C2)` and finally `4. Check if there is a change in grade (D3=D2)`.
Copy this formula down to the rest of your range.
[image: fill formulas]

**Next**, you can start to **pivot**.
Add your pivot table from your table/range with the following
[image: pivot fields]
Filter `Grade Increase` to `true` and also change the values aggregation of `Employee` from `Sum` to `Count`.
You will get the following:
[image: pivot table]

I would rename `Count of Employees` to make it more meaningful.
[image: Field rename]

One caveat for the above approach is that if the grade was increased at the beginning of the 1st `Payroll Period` of the year, the increase won't be captured. For such, you can remove the year check from the formula **A3=A2**.

---

### Edit:

Doing a bit of research, perhaps you can do

```
select t1.*, (t1.Grade > t2.Grade) as Grade_Increase
from YourTableName t1 left join YourTableName t2 on
t1.Employee = t2.Employee and
(((t1.Year - 2018)*26) + t1.Payroll_Period) = 
(((t2.Year - 2018)*26) + t2.Payroll_Period - 1) -- -1 to get the prior record to compare grades
```

What the above does is essentially joining the table to itself.
Records that are 'next in sequence' are combined into the same row. And a comparison is done.
This was not verified in Access.
**Substitute** `2018` with whatever your base year is. I'm using `2018` to calculate the sequence number of the records. Initially I thought of using common table expressions, rank and row_number. But access doesn't seem to support these functions.

Comment: Thank you so much! This would work however, I'm working on about 830,000 lines of data.. Is there a way to put this in access?

Comment: Also Sam, this is showing the grade increase from prior period and not on current period. e.g. if the employee got promoted in period 03 from period 00 it shows true in period 00 which i can't do a -1 period as it varies.. anyway to fix this?

Comment: I am not familar with Access. For your 2nd question, how about the records between 00 and 03? If there are no records in between, I believe a sort in the data would make 00 and 03 adjacent i.e. in sequence? I did state that for this to work, the data needs to be in sequence.

Comment: Thanks Sam. This code worked better for me but I need it in access.=AND(B2<>B3,C2=C3,D3>D2) I think inner join would work with this. Calling all access guru's out there if you can assist. Thanks in advance!